# Conversion of Advection diffusion equation (ADE) into ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, transformation

I have ADE
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}+u_o\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}=D_o \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}$$
where $u_o$ and $D_o$ are constants and initial and B.C. are $c(x,0)=0$ and $c(x_o,t)=c_o, \ \ c(\infty, t) =0$ where $x_o, c_o$ are also constants.

I tried to convert ADE into ODE using transformation $\eta = x - ct \implies C(\eta) = c(x,t)$ where $c$ is transformation parameter, then ODE is
$$(-c+u_o) \frac{\partial C}{\partial \eta}=D_o \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial \eta^2} \ \ \ \ \ \to \ \ \ (1)$$

But one same transformation I found on another thread is [pde - Advection diffusion equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138919/advection-diffusion-equation). The same transformation applied but converted to Diffusion equation not in ODE. Difference is that their chain rule is used but I proceed as follow
$$\frac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial \eta} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}=-c \frac{\partial C}{\partial \eta}$$

**Now question is that, either my result into ODE eq $(1)$ is correct or I should use chain rule and it should be converted into heat equation as in other thread?**

**Added: Also, please help me to apply these transformation on initial and B.C.**
Transformation on condition $c(\infty, t)=0$ is not problem but how I apply these conditions on $c(x_o,t)=c_o$ as for $x=x_o \implies \eta=x_o-ct$ so condition becomes $c(x_o,t)=C(x_o-ct)=c_o$

Comment: What you have is fine. The other post made a coordinate transformation to eliminate the advection term $\partial_{x} f$, only, by transforming the _spatial_ coordinate $x \to x + vt \implies u(x,t) \to u(x+vt,t)$. Your coordinate transformation is letting $u(x,t) \to u(\eta(x,t)) = u(x-ct)$

Comment: @Mattos Is above transformed ODE ok?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: @Mattos. Thanks and can you help me that how I can apply this transformation to initial and boundary conditions?