# Construct solution of $u_t + (|u|)_x = \epsilon u_{xx}$ from solution of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, hyperbolic-equations, parabolic-pde, viscosity-solutions

I am trying to find the vanishing viscosity limit of

$\begin{alignat}{3}
\begin{cases}
u^{\epsilon}_t + (|u^{\epsilon}|)_x &= \epsilon u^{\epsilon}_{xx} &\mathrm{in}  &\mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty) \\
u^{\epsilon}(x, 0) &= u_0^{\epsilon}(x) &\mathrm{on}  &\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\end{alignat}$

where

$u^{\epsilon}_0(x)= \begin{cases}
\phantom{-} 1, \; x>0 \\
-1, \; x<0
\end{cases}$

For that I first look at a solution of the heat equation

$\begin{alignat}{3}
\begin{cases}
v_t^{\epsilon, +} - \epsilon v_{xx}^{\epsilon, +} &= 0 &\mathrm{in}  &\mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty) \\
v^{\epsilon, +}(x, 0) &= v_0^+(x) &\mathrm{on}  &\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\end{alignat}$

with initial data

$v_0^+(x)= \begin{cases}
1, \; x>0 \\
0, \; x<0
\end{cases}$

From the solution of the heat equation we then construction a solution of the first problem with initial data $v_0^+$. After that we do the same for mirrored initial conditions

$v_0^-(x)= \begin{cases}
\phantom{-} 0, \; x>0 \\
-1, \; x<0
\end{cases}$

The vanishing viscosity limit should then arise from a comparison principle and stability of the initial conditions $v_0^+, \, v_0^-$.

I know the solution to the first heat equation problem should be

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4t}}\right)$

where erf denotes the Gauss error function. But I don't know how to use this result to construct a solution to the first problem.

Comment: There is a change of variable that transforms advection-diffusion equations into heat equations (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138919)). To do so, the PDE may be rewritten $u_t^\epsilon + \text{sgn} u^\epsilon \, u^\epsilon_x = \epsilon u_{xx}^\epsilon$